# Using .htaccess to redirect to a subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to 301 redirect from '/en' or '/en/' to '/en/home' using .htaccess, but any attempt I do results into a redirection loop '/en/home/home/home/home/home/home...'.
Shouldn't it be as simple as `Redirect 301 /en /en/home`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect` based rule keep matching `/en` in redirected URL as well. You can use `RedirectMatch` for this with regex support:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(en)/?$ /$1/home
```

Also make sure to clear your browser cache when you test this.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! The htaccess syntax seems so confusing and I still didn't find any good source to learn it. Is it a language of its own, by the way?

Comment: http://askapache.com is pretty good resource. It is not a language but can be considered a scripting platform.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the full URL, example:

redirect 301 /folder_wrong/name.html http://website.com/folder-right/name.html